# Passport.js is not passing user to request in req.login()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

My passport.js configuration goes like so:

```
const Local = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const USMODEL = require("../models/user.js");
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("SERIALIZING USER");
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("DESUSER", id);
    var US = mongoose.model("RegUser", USMODEL);
    US.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, id);
    });
});
passport.use("local-login", new Local({
    usernameField: "email",
    passwordField: "password",
    passReqToCallback: true

},function(req, email, password, done) {
    var US = mongoose.model("RegUser", USMODEL);
    US.findOne({"email": email}, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user) return done(null, false);
        if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
            console.log("password not valid");
            return done(null, false);
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
}));
```

I'm changing the mongoose model within each function because I juggle with multiple collections at a time and I like to have complete control of what's going on.

My router.js file has the following paths that make use of the passport middleware:

```
app.get("/user/login", function(req, res) {
    res.render("signin");
});
app.post('/user/login', function (req, res){
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info){
        if (err) return res.redirect("/");
        if (!user) return res.redirect('/');

        else {
            req.login(user, function(err) {
              if (err) return next(err);
              console.log("Request Login supossedly successful.");
              return res.redirect('/admin/filter');
            });
        }
    })(req, res);
});
```

Which, upon successful authentication, redirects to /admin/filter in the same router that goes like so.

```
app.get("/admin/filter", isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
//rendering stuff here
});
```

Now, the admin/filter request goes past a middleware called `isLoggedIn` which, in theory protects my endpoints. It goes like so:

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
console.log("This is the authentication middleware, is req authenticated?");
console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
console.log("Does req.user exist?")
console.log(req.user);
return next();
}
```

Now, you would expect that because I called req.login and I got redirected to my endpoint of choice, the request would be authenticated. This is not the case.

```
Request Login supossedly successful.
This is the authentication middleware, is req authenticated?
false
Does req.user exist?
undefined
```

I can't seem to find the source of my problem. Everything checks out, as the strategy is being invoked, as well as the callback function and `req.login` which would render, in theory, a `req.user` object with data in it. One odd thing I've observed is that I don't see the `passport.deserializeUser()` method in action. Ever. But that could be tangential to the problem. Passport is definitely using my strategy and rendering a user object, but somehow this same object is not going into the request. Do you have any suggestion or idea about what is going on?

Comment: do u need to `require('passport')` as well? or is `passport-local` taking care of that - i have installed passport from scratch and had similar issues at one point - trying to remember what the problem was.

Comment: try putting `req.login(user...` in your passport.js file in the callback function at the end

Comment: yeah @ewizard passport-local does require the use of passport as it just includes the strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem by juggling around with the tutorial I started with when I first learned how to use the Passport middleware. Turns out I was doing the configuring wrong: My code used to be like this in the server file:

```
pass = require("passport");
app.use(pass.initialize());
app.use(pass.session());
require("./app/config/passport.js")(pass);
```

when it should have been this:

```
pass = require("passport");
require("./app/config/passport.js")(pass);
app.use(pass.initialize());
app.use(pass.session());
```

Either I missed the part in the documentation where it's specified that configuration must come before initialization or it's simply written off as a trivial thing to remark. Either way, I solved my problem.

Comment: No, your previous order is correct or the order does not matter. See the example here: https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-social/blob/master/app.js#L41

Comment: Even if this isn't exactly your issue, make sure you use and call the middleware in the right order because it could very well be the issue, as it was for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `withCredentials: true` while sending the post request.

```
// register
axios.post(uri, {
  email: email,
  password: password,
  confirmPassword: confirmPassword
}, {
  withCredentials: true
})
```