# How to insert signup data in node js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mean

```
exports.signup = function (req, res) {
  // For security measurement we remove the roles from the req.body object
  delete req.body.roles;

  // Init user and add missing fields
  var user = new User(req.body);
  user.provider = 'local';
  user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;

  // Then save the user
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      // Remove sensitive data before login
      user.password = undefined;
      user.salt = undefined;

      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(user);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

I am not understood the meaning of the below 2 lines in my code
    1)   delete req.body.roles;
    2)   req.login(user, function (err) {

an any one please give me the valid explanantion

Comment: `delete req.body.roles;` -> It's syntax of `delete  a key from an JOSN object`.Like here you are deleting the `roles`

Comment: You are using `passport.js` that's why you need to use `req.login`. To get it proper see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171489/passport-js-is-not-passing-user-to-request-in-req-login

Comment: Ohh K ,does this "req.login()" is a predefined function?.

Comment: See the  doc http://passportjs.org/docs/login

Comment: Thank you abdulbarik,its very usefull nw.